# Access: Use scalar correlated subquery result for sorting

Tags: ms-access, correlated-subquery

In Access, is it possible to use the result of a scalar correlated subquery to sort the resultant rows?  This didn't work (returned a sql error):

```
SELECT (SELECT MIN(DateTime)  FROM Appt WHERE  (PatientID = XXX.ID)) AS minDT, XXX.FullName, 
FROM Patient AS XXX
ORDER BY minDT;
```

Replacing the "minDT" in the `ORDER BY` clause with the entire expression didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access won't allow you to use a field expression alias in the `ORDER BY`, but you can use a column's ordinal number ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            (
                SELECT MIN([DateTime])
                FROM Appt
                WHERE (PatientID = XXX.ID)
            ) AS minDT,
            XXX.FullName
        FROM Patient AS XXX
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note I bracketed the `DateTime` field name because I suspect it's a reserved word.

And don't include a comma after the last item in the `SELECT` field expression list.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that didn't work.  The returned rows were in random order.

Comment: The comma was a typo in my question, not in my code.  And DateTime wasn't the problem.   In fact, if all I do is change the ORDER BY clause to be "ORDER BY FullName", the query works.  So the only thing giving the SQL error is the use of "minDT" in the ORDER BY clause.  And, unfortunately, replacing it with "1" (while getting rid of the SQL error) returned the rows in random order.

Comment: Yes, it seems you must put my original suggestion into another subquery in order for Access to respect the parent query `ORDER BY 1`.  I didn't anticipate that.  But I have now created and loaded the tables, and the updated answer does sort as you wanted.

Comment: Very cool.  Worked like a charm.  Thank you for the very helpful and very quick response.

Comment: You're welcome.  I just realized the extra subquery level means you don't actually need `ORDER BY 1` now.  `ORDER BY sub.minDT` should work.

Comment: Even better.  Thanks again.  By the way, I'm pretty new here.  Other than clicking on the "This answered my question" check mark, is there any other way to give a thumbs-up to your answer?

Comment: Not now.  The checkmark is fine.  After you get to 15 reputation points, you can also upvote answers you judge to be useful.